# Reading tabular data with fixed width and missing values

Tags: go, tabular

I'm trying to read a table from disk in Go, with mixed integers and floats, where the width of each field is fixed (every field occupies a fixed number of places, preceded by blanks if too short) and where some values may be missing (and should default to zero).

The file is here: https://celestrak.org/SpaceData/sw20100101.txt

The Fortran format used to read it is written in the header:

```
FORMAT(I4,I3,I3,I5,I3,8I3,I4,8I4,I4,F4.1,I2,I4,F6.1,I2,5F6.1)
```

and the lines looks like this (some of the last lines, with blanks):

```
2014 12 29 2475  2 20 30 23 33 37 47 33 47 270   7  15   9  18  22  39  18  39  21 1.1 5  64 127.1 0 150.4 156.0 131.4 153.3 160.9
2014 12 30 2475  3 30 40 37 20 30 27 27 23 233  15  27  22   7  15  12  12   9  15 0.8 4  66 126.0 0 150.3 156.1 130.3 152.7 161.0
2014 12 31 2475  4 13 23 13 17 20 33 13 17 150   5   9   5   6   7  18   5   6   8 0.4 2  65 129.2 0 150.5 156.3 133.6 152.4 161.3
2015 01 01 2475  5 20 10 10 10 10 20 20 30 130   7   4   4   4   4   7   7  15   6       101 138.0 0 150.7 156.6 142.7 152.1 161.7
2015 01 02 2475  6 30 10 20 20 30 20 30 40 200  15   4   7   7  15   7  15  27  12       113 146.0 0 150.9 157.0 151.0 152.2 162.1
2015 01 03 2475  7 50 30 30 30 30 20 20 10 220  48  15  15  15  15   7   7   4  15       122 149.0 0 151.0 157.2 154.1 152.4 162.4
```

I have been trying a clever format string to use with Sscanf (like "%4d%3d%3d%5d...") but it won't work with blanks, or if the number is not right-aligned to its slot.

I'm looking a way to read it like in Fortran, where:

- Mixed field types (integers, floats, strings) are possible.
- Each column have a fixed size in characters, filling the slot with blanks if necessary, but different columns may have a different size.
- Numeric values may be preceded by zeros.
- Values may be missing, in that case, it gives its zero value.
- Values may be in any position in the slot, not necessarily right-aligned (not the example but it could be possible)

Is there a clever method to read something like this or should I split, trim, check and convert manually every field?

Comment: I think the split/trim method is your best bet. When you read it in, it looks like the order of the bytes is standardized, so you could run through a loop for each line that just grabs bytes n through n+x for each row and converts them accordingly. For example: `date, _ := time.Parse("2006 01 02",string(bytes[0:9]))` and continue on with `val := strconv.Atoi(string.TrimSpace(string(bytes[n:n+x])))` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"
import "strconv"
import "strings"

type scanner struct {
    len   int
    parts []int
}

func (ss *scanner) Scan(s string, args ...interface{}) (n int, err error) {
    if i := len(s); i != ss.len {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("exepected string of size %d, actual %d", ss.len, i)
    }
    if len(args) != len(ss.parts) {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("expected %d args, actual %d", len(ss.parts), len(args))
    }
    n = 0
    start := 0
    for ; n < len(args); n++ {
        a := args[n]
        l := ss.parts[n]
        if err = scanOne(s[start:start+l], a); err != nil {
            return
        }
        start += l
    }
    return n, nil
}

func newScan(parts ...int) *scanner {
    len := 0
    for _, v := range parts {
        len += v
    }
    return &scanner{len, parts}
}

func scanOne(s string, arg interface{}) (err error) {
    s = strings.TrimSpace(s)
    switch v := arg.(type) {
    case *int:
        if s == "" {
            *v = int(0)
        } else {
            *v, err = strconv.Atoi(s)
        }
    case *int32:
        if s == "" {
            *v = int32(0)
        } else {
            var val int64
            val, err = strconv.ParseInt(s, 10, 32)
            *v = int32(val)
        }
    case *int64:
        if s == "" {
            *v = int64(0)
        } else {
            *v, err = strconv.ParseInt(s, 10, 64)
        }
    case *float32:
        if s == "" {
            *v = float32(0)
        } else {
            var val float64
            val, err = strconv.ParseFloat(s, 32)
            *v = float32(val)
        }
    case *float64:
        if s == "" {
            *v = float64(0)
        } else {
            *v, err = strconv.ParseFloat(s, 64)
        }
    default:
        val := reflect.ValueOf(v)
        err = fmt.Errorf("can't scan type: " + val.Type().String())
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    s := newScan(2, 4, 2)
    var a int
    var b float32
    var c int32

    s.Scan("12 2.2 1", &a, &b, &c)
    fmt.Printf("%d %f %d\n", a, b, c)

    s.Scan("1      2", &a, &b, &c)
    fmt.Printf("%d %f %d\n", a, b, c)

    s.Scan("        ", &a, &b, &c)
    fmt.Printf("%d %f %d\n", a, b, c)
}
```

Output:

```
12 2.200000 1
1 0.000000 1
0 0.000000 0
```

Notice that Scan function returns n - number of parsed arguments and err. If value is missing the function will set it to 0. The implementation is mostly taken from fmt.Scanf.

Comment: Thank you @kopiczko, this is a really nice solution! It can easily evolve to use a Fortran-style format to initialize the scanner. Do you mind if I make it a package and put it in my Github?

Comment: You can do that if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You can employ csv encoding with delimiter set to blankspace. Something like this

```
import (
"encoding/csv"
"os"
)
file, _:=os.Open("/SpaceData/sw20100101.txt")
csvreader:=csv.NewReader(file)
csvreader.Comma=' '
csvreader.FieldsPerRecord=33
csvreader.TrimLeadingSpace=true
parsedout, _ := csvreader.Read()
```

here is working example https://play.golang.org/p/Tsp72D4vsR

Comment: I'm not sure if this works when multiple spaces can appear between records. You might want to remove consecutive spaces before.

Comment: The problem with this is that values are not converted to int/float and if there are missing values or values without blanks between them, it will fail.